# Spotfire Data Table Write Back to Database

Tags: spotfire

Can I update columns in my data table and write them back to the database? Basically, it is only a column that I have to update with a Y/N .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 possible ways that I can think of..

1. Iron Python script and update the flags based on marking
2. step 1:Use spotfire standard HTML wrapper that holds your Spotfire analysis

   step 2:Create a Java function in HTML to pass the key identifiers as input that you want to updates the flags and java function to in turn call a stored procedure to switch the flags.
3. Leverage TSSS and write a data function to pass the SQL for sjdbc that helps to connect to database and execute statements...

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with IronPython script, however it's not supported by TIBCO and does not share the information model you create in the Info Designer.

more here: http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/04/write-back-to-database-from-spotfire.html

Comment: The link doesn't come up properly. But. I think I can write back via stored procs. I am not sure how the UI would look though. Can I have a column in a table accept inputs like a spreadsheet? How would I customize this?

Comment: I updated the link to .com instead of .ch. see if that works?

you can use a graphical table to create a clickable area (set a script action on the axis' properties dialog). if you only need a Y/N then clicking the table could toggle between the values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out-of-the-box. You would have to customize the product to attain such functionality.